# android studio error package can not found ? and some error?

Tags: java, android

> Error:Cannot read packageName from
>   C:\Users\G.K.ENGINEERS\AndroidStudioProjects\FARMING\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
>   Error:Element type "manifest" must be followed by either attribute
>   specifications, ">" or "/>".

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".LOGIN_ACTIVITY">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Register_Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".User_Area_Activity"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Post the complete AndroidManifest.xml. Do you have an `<manifest>` tag?

Comment: see my program i have closed manifest also all and please fast help me

Answer (score 1):

> Error:Element type "manifest" must be followed by either attribute
>   specifications, ">" or "/>".

Every application must have an **[AndroidManifest.xml](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)** file (with precisely that name) in its root directory. The manifest file presents essential information about your app to the Android system, information the system must have before it can run any of the app's code.

Did you close your **Manifest Tag** ?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="Your_Package">


    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LOGIN_ACTIVITY"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: ya i will close look my program